# Packing a small number of packages into a fixed number of bins

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of package sizes. There will be a maximum of around 5 different sizes and they may occur a few times (<50).

```
packages = [5,5,5,5,5,5,10,11]
```

I need to pack them into a fixed number of bins, for example 3.

```
number_of_bins = 3
```

The bins may vary in size (sum of the sizes of the packed packages) between 0 and, say, 2 (that is, the difference of the sum of the sizes of the packages in the bins must be equal or nearly equal). So having bins with `[1,2]` (=3) and `[2]` (=2) (difference is 1) is fine, having them with `[10]` (=10) and `[5]` (=5) (difference is 5) is not.

It is possible not to sort all packages into the bins, but I want the solution where a minimum number of packages remains unpacked.

So the best solution in this case (I think) would be

```
bins = [11,5],[10,5],[5,5,5]
remaining = [5]
```

There's probably a knapsack or bin-packing algorithm to do this, but I haven't found it. I'm fine with brute-forcing it, but I'm not sure what's an efficient way to do that.

Is there any efficient way of doing this easily? Did I just miss the relevant search term to find it?

---

Another example:

```
packages = [5,10,12]
number_of_bins = 2
```

leads to

```
bins = [12],[10]
remaining = [5]
```

because

```
bins = [12],[10,5]
```

has bin sizes of 12 and 15 which vary by more than 2.

Analog:

```
packages = [2,10,12]
number_of_bins = 3
```

leads to

```
bins = [2],[],[]
remaining = [12,10]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why would `[11,5],[10,5,5],[5,5,5]` not be a more optimal solution?

Comment: Your description suggests that package size is ignored. Did you mean to write that the bin size varies between 0 and **20**?

Comment: @Roelant I meant the size of what's in the bins shouldn't vary by more than 2. so my example has sizes 16,15,15, yours has 16,20,15 and 20-15 is more than 2.

Comment: @alexis I've tried to clarify, the bin size doesn't matter, only the sum of the sizes of the packages in the bin.

Comment: Wait, you're trying to say that the _difference_ in the total size of each bin to the next bin needs to be bounded? So each bin could become arbitrarily large, as long as the difference from the next one is small. That was not at all clear (still is not, really). Generally one expects that the restriction is the maximum capacity of each bin.

Comment: @alexis yes exactly. I'm not sure how to say it clearer. There is a limit for the bins, but it's not reache in this part. I add more stuff later (in other dimensions too) and that's when I reach the limit, so I can completly ignore it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [pulp](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/index.html):

```
from pulp import *

packages = [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 65, 65, 65]
number_of_bins = 3
bins = range(1, number_of_bins + 1)
items = range(0, len(packages))

x = LpVariable.dicts('x',[(i,b) for i in items for b in bins],0,1,LpBinary)
y = LpVariable('y', 0, 2, LpInteger)
prob=LpProblem("bin_packing",LpMinimize)

#maximize items placed in bins
prob.setObjective(LpAffineExpression([(x[i,b], -3) for i in items for b in bins] + [(y, 1)]))

#every item is placed in at most 1 bin
for i in items:
    prob+= lpSum([x[i,b] for b in bins]) <= 1

for b in bins:
    if b != 1: # bin 1 is the one with lowest sum
        prob+= LpAffineExpression([(x[i,b], packages[i]) for i in items]  + [(x[i,1], -packages[i]) for i in items])  >= 0
    if b != number_of_bins: # last bin is the one with highest
        prob+= LpAffineExpression([(x[i,number_of_bins], packages[i]) for i in items]  + [(x[i,b], -packages[i]) for i in items])  >= 0

#highest sum - lowest sum <= 2 so every difference of bin sums must be under 2
prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[i,number_of_bins], packages[i]) for i in items]  + [(x[i,1], -packages[i]) for i in items]) <= 2  
prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[i,number_of_bins], packages[i]) for i in items]  + [(x[i,1], -packages[i]) for i in items]) == y

prob.solve()
print(LpStatus[prob.status])

for b in bins:
    print(b,':',', '.join([str(packages[i]) for i in items if value(x[i,b]) !=0 ]))
print('left out: ', ', '.join([str(packages[i]) for i in items if sum(value(x[i,b]) for b in bins) ==0 ]))
```

Comment: This is just great! Thanks a lot! Is it possible to easily minimize the value (size) of the remainder and maybe even of the difference between the bins without losing performance? It would be a *nice to have* feature ;-)

Comment: @DonQuiKong at the moment the script is minimizing the amount of items left out of bins, you would want to minimize the sum of sizes of the left out items instead? Minimizing the different between bins is not possible with this model, because we can only choose to miminize one function, and the rest are constraints. However, you could easily do a loop from 0 to 2 and run code with making the constraint of difference between bins that value and solve each of those 3 problems, then compare the results to suit your needs

Comment: Not instead, additionally. But I just found out that inputting a reverse-sorted list will do the trick. (Example: ´[18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 65, 65, 65]´ returns ´bins
[[65, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18], [18, 18, 65, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18]] and  remainder [65]´, however if the input is sorted to start with the 65s, the remainder will be [18] (and the bins different).

Comment: Damn, how do you do code in comments? That's just unreadable, sorry, I tried. Anyways, I was also thinking about changing "prob.setObjective(lpSum([x[i,b] for i in items for b in bins]))" to something like prob.setObjective(100000000*lpSum([x[i,b] for i in items for b in bins]+lpSum([i for i in items for b in bins])) which should also do the trick? But I don't know how that performs and sorting seems fine.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I am not aware if pulp will always give the answer you desire with sorting. You could replace 100000000 with the sum of sizes of items, no idea if that would make it slower or its the same. Another option is first run it as it is to know the minimum amount x of items you can leave outside, and then run another solve with the additional constraint of the amount left outside being x and minimizing instead the sum of the ones left outside

Comment: I'm not so inclined to run it another time because I need the program to finish in a reasonable amount of time and I'm already having trouble with that (it goes up and down). But thanks for the help, I'll play with this some more, it's exactly what I needed to get things going.

Comment: @DonQuiKong wasnt it taking like 2s? How fast you need it to be :o

Comment: It seems to vary a bit depending on the input. But even 2 seconds is a lot if you run it 200 times ;) I've started to group the packages into bigger packages which speeds it up a lot. E.g. if number_of_bins is 3 then there should never be more than 5 instances of a package ([1,1,1,1,1]) because if there's 6 times the 1 then [2,1,1,1,1] would be identical. makes it a lot faster if there are 15 or so instances of 1 package for 2 or 3 bins.

Comment: @DonQuiKong give me an example that takes "a lot" and I can try a few things

Comment: [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 65, 65, 65] distributed to 3 bins takes slighty over a minute (in debug modus though). But it's fine, I change the input to [72, 65, 65, 65, 36, 36, 36, 36, 18, 18, 18, 18] which get's it down to 0.7 seconds in debug mode and has the same solutions.

Comment: @DonQuiKong takes 14s without debug mode on my pc. Modified code to a way of restricting the difference with less constrains (n instead of n^2). Runs in 4.3s now. You can also try changing the solver

Comment: @DonQuiKong 0.4s now and also optimizes difference between bins if there is a tie on left out items ^^

Comment: nice :) I'll test it on monday

Comment: I've adapted it to minimze the sum of the left out packages with `y = pulp.LpVariable('y', 0, max(packages), pulp.LpInteger)` and `prob += pulp.LpAffineExpression([(x[i,b], packages[i]) for i in items for b in bins]) == sum(packages) - y` but do you think there is a way to make it give me all solutions with the same number of remaining packages? (Thanks again for the help)

Comment: @DonQuiKong one way would be [using SCIP](https://www.aiexp.info/calculating-all-feasible-solutions-of-ilp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one, really not sure about an optimal solution. Below is a solution that just iterates all possible groups and halts at the first solution. This should be a minimal-remainder solution since we first iterate through all solutions without any remainder.

It also iterates over solutions as *everything in the first bin*, which could be excluded for a faster result.

```
import numpy as np

def int_to_base_list(x, base, length):
    """ create a list of length length that expresses a base-10 integer
        e.g. binary: int2list(101, 2, 10) returns array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
    """
    placeholder = np.array([0] * length)  # will contain the actual answer
    for i in reversed(range(length)):
        # standard base mathematics, see http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/18
        placeholder[i] = x % base  
        x //= base
    return placeholder

def get_groups(packages, max_diff_sum, number_of_bins):
    """ Get number_of_bins packaging groups that differ no more than max_diff_sum
        e.g. 
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 11] with 2, 3 gives [5,5,5], [10,5], [11,5]
        [5, 10, 12] with 2, 2 gives [10], [12]
        [2, 6, 12] with 2, 3 gives [2], [], []

        We approach the problem by iterating over group indices, so the first
        example above has solution [0 0 0 1 2 3 1 2] with the highest number being
        the 'remainder' group. 
    """
    length = len(packages)
    for i in range((number_of_bins + 1)**length - 1):  # All possible arrangements in groups 
        index = int_to_base_list(i, number_of_bins + 1, length)  # Get the corresponding indices
        sums_of_bins = [np.sum(packages[index==ii]) for ii in range(number_of_bins)]
        if max(sums_of_bins) - min(sums_of_bins) <= max_diff_sum:  # the actual requirement 
            # print(index)
            break
    groups = [packages[index==ii] for ii in range(number_of_bins)] 
    # remainder = packages[index==number_of_bins+1]
    return groups
```

On your examples:

```
packages = np.array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 11])
max_diff_sum = 2
number_of_bins = 3
get_groups(packages, max_diff_sum, number_of_bins)

>> [array([5, 5, 5]), array([ 5, 10]), array([ 5, 11])]
```

And

```
packages = np.array([5,10,12])
max_diff_sum = 2
number_of_bins = 2
get_groups(packages, max_diff_sum, number_of_bins)

>> [array([10]), array([12])]
```

Comment: I'll try this out, probably not before friday (got to go now), and report back. Is is fast enough to go through up to maybe 50 (probably rather less) packages in up to 6 bins?

Comment: @DonQuiKong that would mean 6**50, so no

Comment: I tried the pulp solution and this one with 40 packages and 6 bins, the pulp version ran <2 seconds, then I went for coffee and some chat and this one hadn't finished when I returned. Thank you anyways, but it seems that this would only work if one somehow used the fact that most packages will have a size choosen from maybe 3 or 4 different sizes. But I like the iterating over the list of bins for every package, that's a nice trick. Just brainstorming: it might be possible to vectorize the for loop to get a big performance boost.