# How to partition n numbers in k containers, so that they are balanced?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have n numbers and I want to distribute them among k containers (n/k numbers in each container) such that the difference between each two container is minimized. 
 1. Is 'balanced partitioning' the best map of this question? 
2. I  found all of the 'balanced partition' discussions on 2 containers (such as [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612056/distribute-numbers-to-two-containers-and-minimize-their-difference-of-sum)). How can I extend the solutions for more containers?

Comment: So what have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share your findings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packing a small number of packages into a fixed number of bins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084341/packing-a-small-number-of-packages-into-a-fixed-number-of-bins)

Comment: @MrSmith42, If I have k as power of 2, I can use divide and conquer and partition problem (so in each phase, I would partition n numbers two 2 groups)

Comment: @juvian, thanks for the link. In that link, there is an objective function of minimizing the left-out terms. I don't have any objective function, how can I map it to linear programming?

Comment: @Shabnam your objective is that the difference between two containers is minimized. Your restriction is that n/k numbers go in each container

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is indeed a generalization of the well-known `Partition` problem. (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem for more information on the subject), and hence it is a NP-hard problem.

Your problem is, to be more precise, the `Multi-Way Number Partitioning`, introduced in many articles recently, for example in https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/09/Papers/096.pdf and in http://www.mysmu.edu/faculty/kyriakos/IJCAI11.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will take a look at them.