# How can N integers be divided into M equally sized groups such that the difference between their maximum and minimum sums is minimum?

Tags: algorithm, math, greedy, partition-problem

How can N integers be divided into M equally sized groups such that the difference between their maximum and minimum sums is minimum?

I see that it belongs to the partition kind of problems, but I didn't find a solution that matches both "M > 2" and "equally sized" criteria

Comment: how can we divide odd n like 5 or 7 in equal-sized groups? and what is meant by the difference between their maximum and minimum sums is minimum? can you please show an example?

Comment: See [balanced number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_number_partitioning); this is a (still NP-hard) variant of multiway number partitioning with cardinality constraints. Your problem has been asked before here, but I can't find a thread with a good answer (for instance, [this question seems identical.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718029/how-to-partition-n-numbers-in-k-containers-so-that-they-are-balanced))